# Sql queries to find all records with no corresponding values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can someone help me with this please,

I have two tables

TableA with records

```
A | A1 
A | A2 
A | A3 
B | B1
```

TableB

```
A1 | x 
A2 | y
```

I want to retrieve records which do not have any corresponding value in the TableB. Basically, I want to output as follow...

Result :

```
B | B1
```

How can write a query?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Why both `mysql` & `sql-server` they are different?
Why only B|B1 and not A|A3

Comment: I tried queries with all possible join ,COLLATE etc. where B.id is null something of sort but no luck. @Abhishek : Am testing my queries in sql-server and mysql , so its sufficient if it works in those DB.

Comment: Don't post what you've tried as a comment, [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50447724/edit) your question. And please tag the correct RDBMS. Like @Abhishek has said, `mysql` and`sql-server` are completely different services, and the syntax can be just as different.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use OUTER JOIN:

```
    SELECT
      TableA.*
    FROM TableA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
      ON TableB.Field1 = TableA.Field2
    WHERE TableB.Field1 IS NULL
```

2. Use EXISTS:

```
SELECT
  TableA.*
FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM TableB
  WHERE TableB.Field1 = Table1A.Field2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_a 
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT table_a.col1
               FROM   table_a
               JOIN 
               table_b 
               ON (table_b.col1 = table_a.col2))
```

Use [this](http://rextester.com/USLFAK33151) link for Demo

Comment: Sorry , i was bit early in sending response . It doesnt work as expected. The expected output is  B | B1  but am getting an additional row A | A3  as well.

Comment: Check if this is your exact requirements

Answer (score 0):

Definition of tables and sample data:

```
create table Tbl1 (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));
insert into Tbl1 values ('A','A1');
insert into Tbl1 values ('A','A2');

create table Tbl2 (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));
insert into Tbl2 values ('A1','y');
```

and the query to return desired results (works for both: MS SQL and MySql):

```
select * from Tbl1
where col2 not in (select col1 from Tbl2 where col1 is not null)
```

If you are confused by `where` clause in subquery, this is only to avoid `NULL` values, as they might introduce unexpected (empty) results.